# Http as a source for Nifi - not working as expected

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to send a file through postman with a POST request and that file needs to be saved in the local FS. I tried all the 4 options `GetHttp,InvokeHttp,ListenHttp,HandleHttpRequest`. Seems like `GetHttp,InvokeHttp` requires a webservice to be running at the end who is sending the POST request, that would not fit our case use case. I tried using `ListenHttp` but I am not able to change the default hostname option which it is pointing to localhost. Is there a way to change that?

And I tried using `HandleHttpRequest` as well, and it seems like the client who is receiving the request should send an acknowledgement to end the connection at the sender side, nifi user guide doesn't provide an example on how to use or configure that. Can someone provide me an example for the use case which I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListenHttp starts an embedded Jetty server and it does not specify a hostname when creating the connector which according to Jetty documentation says that it should be binding to all available network interfaces:

> "The network interface this connector binds to as an IP address or a
>   hostname.  If null or 0.0.0.0, then bind to all interfaces."

To use HandleHttpRequest you also need to use HandleHttpResponse... you basically receive a request from a client which turns into a flow file, pass the flow file through whatever processing you want to do, and then send it to HandleHttpResponse to reply back to the client. There is a template here that shows how to use it:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/57904847/Hello_NiFi_Web_Service.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1449369797000&api=v2

Comment: Thanks. I will try out HandlHttpRequest with HandleHttpResponse